# Python Multiprocessing File Read

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a **list of keywords** and I want to validate if any of these keywords are inside a file containing more than 100,000 domain names. For faster processing, I want to implement **multiprocessing** so that each keyword can be validated in parallel.

My code doesn't seem to be working well as single processing is much faster. What's wrong? :(

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def multiprocessing_func(keyword):

    # File containing more than 100k domain names
    # URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CERT-MZ/projects/master/Domain-squatting/domain-names.txt
    file_domains = open("domain-names.txt", "r")

    for domain in file_domains:
        if keyword in domain:
            print("similar domain identified:", domain)
            
    # Rewind the file, start from the begining
    file_domains.seek(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    starttime = time.time()

    # Keywords to check
    keywords = ["google","facebook", "amazon", "microsoft", "netflix"]

    # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    pool = Pool()  

    for keyword in keywords:
        print("Checking keyword:", keyword)
        
        # Without multiprocessing pool
        #multiprocessing_func(keyword)
        
        # With multiprocessing pool
        pool.map(multiprocessing_func, keyword)

    # Total run time
    print('That took {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

Comment: you should just do `pool.map(multiprocessing_func, keywords)`

Comment: Note that much of the delay of the parallel method is due to printing. The printing messages are ordered which takes a huge amount of time. If I comment out the print statement in the function, I get a x60 speedup in the parallel task on my machine. (However that time  is still x2 the time of the single thread solution. For that, refer to the answer)

Comment: @MarkTolonen I agree that reading the file multiple times is hugely unnecessary, but I think there are a few things that need to addressed in the set approach you suggested: 0. this code is clearly a multithreading exercise and not an application, so the goal is to use multi processing. 1. How would you use a set to search for substrings?? would you insert the whole domain? if so the set is useless as it has to be iterated. would you split by some notion of words? How would you define them? And if so, a trie data structure is a better option. [1/2]

Comment: ... 2. Asymptotic complexity is not a relevant measurement in most cases when we are talking about multiprocessing, as it disregards linear-time speedups - which are crucial in many non-algorithmic applications. [2/2]

Comment: @kyriakosSt Didn't notice the code was doing a "keyword in <string>".  Mis-read as "keyword in <list>" which could use a set.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for the tips... this is a "learning code" so that I can learn how to multiprocess. Based on Tim's tip, I did fix my code however I am not getting the performance improvement that I expected. Iterating the code once to a List is definitely much better than reading the file multiple times, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Think about why this program:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def work(keyword):
    print("working on", repr(keyword))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
        pool.map(work, "google")
```

prints

```
working on 'g'
working on 'o'
working on 'o'
working on 'g'
working on 'l'
working on 'e'
```

`map()` works on a sequence, and a string *is* a sequence.  Instead of sticking the `map()` call in a loop, you presumably want to invoke it only once with `keywords` (the whole list) as its second argument.